# How do I prevent Meteor from sending all documents in a collection to the client?

Tags: javascript, meteor

When using Meteor.subscribe() how do I turn off the default "subscribe to all documents of a collection" behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, new meteor apps include the `autopublish` package, which is responsible for that behavior. To stop that from happening, remove the package by typing `meteor remove autopublish` in the command line from your meteor app home directory.

See http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity for more info:

> By default, a new Meteor app includes the autopublish and insecure packages, which together mimic the effect of each client having full read/write access to the server's database. These are useful prototyping tools, but typically not appropriate for production applications. When you're ready, just remove the packages.

Comment: Still gotta wait until the end of the two day period before stack overflow lets me do it :).